# How to change x-axis position using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have the problem, with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) BarChart, I want to display the x-axis values between the 2 lines not on the top of the line like this:

[image]

0,1,2, are months, so I wan't to write down the months between 0 and 1 for example, so the bar will be drown on the middle